# Postgres: Exporting from public schema and importing into another schema

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

In postgres database, Is it possible to export data tables from public schema and import into another schema. I have having error while following the regular way of export and import.

Regards
Xian

Comment: `CREATE <new_schema>.<table_name> AS SELECT  * FROM <old_schema>.<table_name>`? Though you would need space to hold two copies at least temporarily. Also you would need to pay attention to foreign key relationships and inter-schema dependencies.

Comment: The first step in fixing an error is reading the error message and attached DETAIL and HINT messages and contemplating what they mean.